# Match Results by team_id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have table like teams, matches and leagues the following screen shots and I need find team results for related team_id. (Home and Away results)

**teams table fields:**
*team_id, team_name*

**leagues table fields:**
*league_id, league_name*

**matches table fields:**
*match_id, match_date, home_team_id, a.team_id, home_score, away_score, league_id*

I can find all results as below query, but how can I find results by team_id.

My needs is finding correct results by using example : **where = team_id="21"** and shows ** Arsenal's Home & AWAY all matches.**

All Results (Home and Away) by league_id query is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.week,
            m.match_date,
            h.team_name AS Home,
            a.team_name AS AWAY,
            m.home_score,
            m.away_score,
            m.league_id
FROM matches m,
     teams h,
     teams a,
     leagues l
WHERE h.team_id=m.home_team_id
  AND a.team_id=m.away_team_id
  AND m.league_id=2;
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWyDs.png)

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

Regards.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: That's the third time you have asked this and the question keeps getting closed - perhaps it;s a poor question - please add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images that we can't and please make the question self contained - not everyone will be able to see links

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask particularly the section headed Help others reproduce the problem

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help]
PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Comment: Do not repost questions, edit per feedback. Especially don't circumvent closing. [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For A particular  league

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.week,
            m.match_date,
            h.team_name AS Home,
            a.team_name AS AWAY,
            m.home_score,
            m.away_score,
            m.league_id
FROM matches m,
     teams h,
     teams a,
     leagues l
WHERE h.team_id=m.home_team_id
  AND a.team_id=m.away_team_id
  AND l.id=m.league_id
  AND m.league_id=2
  AND (m.home_team_id = 21 or m.away_team_id = 21) ;
```

for any league

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.week,
            m.match_date,
            h.team_name AS Home,
            a.team_name AS AWAY,
            m.home_score,
            m.away_score,
            m.league_id
FROM matches m,
     teams h,
     teams a,
     leagues l
WHERE h.team_id=m.home_team_id
  AND a.team_id=m.away_team_id
  AND l.id=m.league_id
  AND (m.home_team_id = 21 or m.away_team_id = 21) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Segun Adeniji. It's working. I just added one column as W,L and Draw for checking scores. But I cannot solve related teams results as W,L or D correctly. Only checking results by hometeam. Maybe you can help me with seeing my above comments regarding Hame and Away matches same team_id W,L and D correctly.. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler to understand if you use explicit joins for example

```
drop table if exists teams,leagues,matches;

create table teams (team_id int, team_name varchar(3));

create table leagues(league_id int, league_name varchar(3));

create table matches 
(match_id int, match_date date, home_team_id int, a_team_id int, home_score int, away_score int, league_id int);

insert into teams values (1,'t1'),(2,'t2');
insert into leagues values(1,'l1');
insert into matches values 
(1,'2022-01-01','1','2',10,50,1),
(2,'2022-01-01','2','1',10,50,1);

select m.*,t1.team_name hometeam,t2.team_name awayteam,l.league_name
from   matches m
join   teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
join   teams  t2 on m.a_team_id = t2.team_id
join   leagues l on l.league_id = m.league_id
where  m.home_team_id = '1' or m.a_team_id = 1;
```

+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------

```
-+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
| match_id | match_date | home_team_id | a_team_id | home_score | away_score | league_id | hometeam | awayteam | league_name |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
|        2 | 2022-01-01 |            2 |         1 |         10 |         50 |         1 | t2       | t1       | l1          |
|        1 | 2022-01-01 |            1 |         2 |         10 |         50 |         1 | t1       | t2       | l1          |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)


select m.*,t1.team_name hometeam,t2.team_name awayteam,l.league_name,
         CASE WHEN m.home_score > m.away_score THEN 'W' 
              WHEN m.home_score < m.away_score THEN 'L' 
                WHEN m.home_score = m.away_score THEN 'D' 
         END AS results
from   matches m
join   teams  t1 on m.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
join   teams  t2 on m.a_team_id = t2.team_id
join   leagues l on l.league_id = m.league_id
where  m.home_team_id = '1' or m.a_team_id = 1;

+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| match_id | match_date | home_team_id | a_team_id | home_score | away_score | league_id | hometeam | awayteam | league_name | results |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
|        2 | 2022-01-01 |            2 |         1 |         10 |         50 |         1 | t2       | t1       | l1          | L       |
|        1 | 2022-01-01 |            1 |         2 |         10 |         50 |         1 | t1       | t2       | l1          | L       |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Dear P.Salmon, I just check real results I think there is a little mistake. Because your latest update shown if hometeam t2 always lost when t1 win in away. In my example t1 is  Arsenal so when they win in away result is shows as LOST. Home matches results are correct only.'Brentford','2','Arsenal','0','Premier League','W'
'Arsenal','0','Chelsea','2','Premier League','L'
'Manchester City','5','Arsenal','0','Premier League','W'
'Arsenal','1','Norwich City','0','Premier League','W'
'Burnley','0','Arsenal','1','Premier League','L'
'Arsenal','3','Tottenham Hotspur','1','Premier League','W'

Comment: The results column was based on your logic and always reflects the home team result - in simple words what do you want to see -and this should be added to the question.

Comment: If user choose team_id=21 (like Arsenal) when rersult will be given by only Arsenal's team_id. Examples: Arsenal - Chelsea = 2-0 as WON, Chelsea - Arsenal = 0-2 as WON and  Arsenal - Chelsea = 0-2 as LOST, Chelsea - Arsenal = 2-0 has to be LOST as result.